# I changed the order of the template struct in C++ and got an error

Tags: c++, templates

this code works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    static const int result = N * Factorial<N - 1>::result;
};
template <>
struct Factorial<1> {
    static const int result = 1;
};


int main() {

    std::cout << Factorial<6>::result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but, this code doesn't work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <>
struct Factorial<1> {
    static const int result = 1;
};
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    static const int result = N * Factorial<N - 1>::result;
};


int main() {

    std::cout << Factorial<6>::result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the error list is...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAPXS.png)

Since Factorial needs to reference it, I think Factorial<1> should be on top.
However, an error occurred that was not what I expected.

Comment: 1. yes, you can't write the specilization before the general template, 2. I can't read corean error messages, 3. don't post images, but paste text (in English).

Comment: Why would you post an _image_ of errors and not text? Even worse is the errors are not even in English... Template specialization has to occur after the template though.

Comment: Because the two structs are not equal. One is a specialization of the other, the specialization must come after the primary template.

Comment: You need to declare the template before you can specialize it.

Comment: The rules of C++ are not as you thought. In this case the general template must be seen before a template that specialises it (how else can the compiler know what it's specialising).

Answer (score 1):

`template <> struct Factorial<1>` is [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of `template <int N> struct Factorial`. The template itself must come before its specialization.

When you write `Factorial<N - 1>`, you are using `template <int N>`. The specialization is resolved later once the value of `N` is known.

You may compare this logic to a function call: Function declaration `void function(int);` must come before `function(1);`, as the function call uses the function, not the other way around.